# Store controller response in a JSP variable

Tags: jsp, controller

I've got a Spring controller used to perform a passive log in. The method returns a JSON that contains information to be used later in the app.

I should call the controller via JSP and then pass the result to a JavaScript.

How can I call the controller and store the result?

I tried using `<jsp:include page="login.do?param1=x&param2=y"/>` but the controller is not being called

Comment: Why wouldn't you call it via JS?

Comment: I need the call to be made by the server, not the client

Comment: ... That doesn't seem relevant; make the JS call to the server, the server calls whatever you're doing, then passes it back. Regardless, whatever it is you're doing, without knowing how you're trying to "pass the result to a JavaScript", it's impossible to help.

Comment: Let's say I just want to print the JSON in the HTML

Comment: Then you'd either need to escape the response for JS if you want it accessible from JS, or just dump it from a request attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following code in the `<head>` section of my page to retrieve the response

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%    
  String recv;
  String recvbuff = "";
  URL jsonpage = new URL("http://somehost/logon.do?username=abc&password=123");
  URLConnection urlcon = jsonpage.openConnection();
  BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));

  while ((recv = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
    recvbuff += recv;
  }
  buffread.close();

%>
```

and then in the javascript

```
<script>
  ...
  var credentials = JSON.parse('<%= recvbuff%>');

</script>
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it but it works.